# Doctrine in random ocassions duplicates existing entrys in a OneToMany relation

Tags: php, symfony, merge, doctrine-orm, flush

I have a device that can have multiple states having here a One To many relation.

The problem is that sometimes and totally randomly instead of updating the device info with the new states it creates a new device.

I put logs everywhere in order to see if any error happens but there is no errors and everyday it creates some random new entries and I cannot replicate this error by changing the states values.

DEVICE

```
/**
* device
*
* @ORM\Table(name="Device", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="FK_Device_Client", 
columns={"client"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_Device_Instalation1_idx", columns= 
{"instalation"})})
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="tipo", type="integer")
}


abstract class Device
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;
```

CHANGE STATE

```
   private $device;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InformacionEnviada", mappedBy="changeState")
 */
```

Controller

Now the controller is a bit complicated because there are many cases to consider, so I only put the doctrine calls for better understanding but I notice that some flush method are being called in the same run for the same device so I think something may be wrong here.

```
foreach($devices as $device){
   if(Condition){
      $this->em->merge($device);
      IF(Condition){
         $this->em->getConnection()->executeUpdate('UPDATE ChangeState SET date_time_end = ? WHERE device= ? AND date_time_end is null', array($nowString ,  $device->getId()));
        $this->em->flush();
   }    

   $this->em->persist($changeState);
   $this->em->merge($device);
   $this->em->flush();
   }

  $this->em->merge($device);
  $this->em->flush();
}
```

This code is working fine and the states are being added to the device, but randomly I get new entries, and I cannot replicate the error, but one of the iterations that got duplicate executed this query and then flushed, so maybe the error is here.

```
$this->em->getConnection()->executeUpdate('UPDATE ChangeState SET date_time_end = ? WHERE device= ? AND date_time_end is null', array($nowString ,  $device->getId()));
        $this->em->flush();
```

Can you help me please? I'm so lost here and I cannot figure out the error.

Comment: I can't really follow your code but using getConnection in conjunction with the entity manager is a very bad idea.  The entity manager has no idea what happens when you use getConnection.  If I had to speculate the problem occurs when you have multiple users running your code at the same time.  Get rid of the getConnection stuff and, if at all possible, add an actual database constraint to prevent this sort of thing from happening at the database level.  At least you would get an error log of some sort.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, this command is being executed in the server so there is no any other user executing it.

Now i'm closing the connection in order to see if I get any other duplicates but I don't get any log error, so i'm not going anywhere if this fails.

Can you tell me what is the best aproach then to update the changeState please? get the changeState by findBy and then seting the parameter and finally use persist and flush?